# Know when a user leaves component - React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I'm building an app that uses React, Redux, Firebase and the function onSnapshot(). I read that to lower costs and updates to the server is good practice to unsubscribe the onSnapshot when the user leaves the component.

So my question is: How can I know when a user leaves a component or a path in react to unsuscribe the onSnapshot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a React class component, use `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` to add and remove listeners or subscriptions:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Add listeners, subscriptions, etc.
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove listeners, subscriptions, etc.
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

In a React function component, use the `useEffect` hook to do the same. Be sure to add the proper dependencies in `useEffect`'s dependency array (second argument).

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Add listeners, subscriptions, etc.

    return () => {
      // This function will be called just before the component unmounts.
      // Remove listeners, subscriptions, etc.       
    };
  }, [/* Dependency array */]);

  return (...);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillUnmount() { // your Code here }
```

"This method is called when a component is being removed from the DOM" (from: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). Hope that is what you were looking for.